# Controlling Conditional Features with a Radio Button

Tags: wix

My problem is that I would like to allow the user to install an optional component group based on a radio-button selection.
The radio button and the Condition specified in the Feature are both bound to a Property called "InstallType". InstallType will be set to 1 to install only "client" files, but 2 to install both client and server files.

The conditional installation works correctly, based on the initial value of InstallType, but when the user changes InstallType the new value is ignored.

Here is the code in the dialog:

```
<Fragment>
    <Property Id="InstallType" Value ="1"/>
    <UI>
      <Dialog
        Id ="InstallationTypeDlg" Width ="370" Height ="270" Title ="Test Install Type" NoMinimize ="no">
          <Control Id ="Text1" Type ="Text" Text ="Choose Install Type:" Height="17" Width="200" X="10" Y="15" />
          <Control Id ="InstallTypeRadioGroup" Type ="RadioButtonGroup" Property="InstallType" X="50" Y="35" Height ="40" Width ="300">
          <RadioButtonGroup Property ="InstallType">
            <RadioButton Value ="1" Text ="ClientOnly" Height ="17" Width ="90" X="0" Y="10" />
            <RadioButton Value ="2" Text ="ClientAndServer" Height ="17" Width ="90" X="0" Y="10" />
          </RadioButtonGroup>
        </Control>   
      </Dialog>
    </UI>
  </Fragment>
```

And here is the code in Product.wxs:

```
<Feature Id="ClientOnly" Title="Client Only" Level="1">
    <ComponentGroupRef Id="ClientProductComponents" />
</Feature>
<Feature Id="ClientAndServer" Title="Client And Server" Level="0">
    <ComponentGroupRef Id="ServerProductComponents" />
      <Condition Level="1" >
        <![CDATA[InstallType = "2"]]>
      </Condition>
</Feature>
```

As shown, the code will always install the Client files, but never the Server.
If InstallType is initialized as "2", both Component Groups are installed, as expected.
I can force the outcome by hard-coding "true" or "false" in the condition evaluation.

The only thing that doesn't seem to be working is that toggling the radio button has no effect on InstallType as seen inside Product.wxs.
If I put a Text box in a dialog downstream of the radio-button dialog, I can see that InstallType contains the correct value.

I am using WIX 3.10 and VS2015.

Anyone have any idea what's wrong? 
All responses appreciated.
Thanks,
Warren

Comment: Well,  I got this to work by following the suggestion made earlier: On exiting the dialog, remove all the features. Then replace ("publish" them based on the setting of the radio buttons. If anyone has a good understanding of the relationship between this remove-publish action in the dialog and the eventual installation of the features, it would be very helpful. Seems pretty mysterious at this point. ...but at least its working :)

Comment: I'm also trying to figure out how to do something very similar.  Would you mind posting the working result as an answer and then marking it correct?  Thanks!